# transmitter not connecting in multiwii

Tags: quadcopters, fs-i6x, arduino-drone

i built a drone usiong multiwii controller and uncommented drone x and mpu6050 lines i calibrated the motors using it also but when i operate transmitter using multiwii software the software and drone is not recieving i even checked the connections and am stuck with this problem now.
i am using _
arduino uno
mpu 6050
flysky fsi6
and 1800 kv motors
when i connect the battery noting happens but when i connet the board to computer the motors start rotating
the software is properly responding to the gyro sensor but not transmitter

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the ppm setting in transmitter